# Parallelism - Shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, parallel-processing, xargs

I would like to run two commands in my script. The fist runs a test and the second queries this test to obtain a test id.

Now, the problem is that the second command works ONLY WHILE the first command is running (and of course, after it started). So i can't run it sequentially.
As far as i can understand, i need some sort of parallelism, which should allow the 2 processes to run in parallel. This would allow the second command to obtain the ID from the first, as it is still running.

Point is: i don't have and i can't install Parallel on this machine. I saw also xargs, but doesn't seem to suite for this task.
Any ideas?

The command looks something like this:

```
run test | list test running
```

Thanks

**Edit**
This is how the report looks like. It has many different parameters but the first one is the one i need.

```
ID             | 94503
Name           | Test 
...
```

To grab the ID i use:

```
sed -n '1p' | sed 's/^.\{,17\}//' > test_id.dat
```

Which give me back the ID number.

Piping won't work. The point is that after `run test`, the problem in fact is that when I start the test, the "shell remains busy" with the test execution. The second command, on the other hand, can retrieve this ID only while the test is running. Example: if I start the test from two separate sessions (one local, one ssh) I can get the expected result.

**Edit 2**
Some additional details. In order to obtain the "test id", i've to run a commnad which lists all current running tests (`list test running`).
I follow the advices and wrote something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
list test running > test_running.dat | {
    run test
    cat test_running.dat | sed -n '1p' | sed 's/^.\{,17\}//' > test_id.dat
    cat test_id.dat
}
```

The problem here (no matter which command i put first) is that i get as result in the file "No test running". Meaning that the `list test running` gets executed to early or to late, but in any case not WHILE `run test` is running.

Comment: `run test & obtain test id `

Comment: Can you provide a sample output of `run test`? Where's the ID in it?

Comment: You really need to provide more details.  How does the 2nd obtain the id?  What is the IPC?  (Does it attach to a socket, or some shared memory, or does it read from a fifo?). It seems you can probably do exactly what you wrote: `command1 | command2` to get the parallelism you want.  Why does that pipeline not work?

Comment: What are the commands that you want to run once you got the ID?

Comment: @Fravadona the idea is 1) start the test 2) AFTER the test started but WHILE is running, i want to get the ID 3) Parse the ID (since i won't get only the ID but a whole output) 4) save the result in a txt or dat file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### update

From what I understand the output of `run test` is irrelevant because you'll get the ID with the `list test running` command.

I would say that you can simply wait that `list test running` gives you the ID. Here I use a bash regex based on *"**how the report looks like**"* so you might have to adjust it.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

run test &

# bash regex for capturing the test ID from the output of 'list test running'
# REMARK: it is based on "how the report looks like" in your question
regex='^ID *\| *([0-9]+)'

while ! [[ $(list test running) =~ $regex ]] && jobs -rp | awk 'END{exit(NR==0)}'
do
    sleep 1
done

test_id=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}

[[ $test_id ]] && echo "I got the test-ID: $test_id"

wait
```

---

###### old answer

So `run test` starts by outputting a line with the ID and then continue computing and outputting whatever it might be?
It's not clear how you'll use that ID but the following code should show you a way to get what you want and run a command with it while `run test` continue executing:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

run test | {
    IFS= read -r line          # catch the first line (containing the ID)

    obtain test "${line:17}" & # launch the other command as a sub-process

    printf '%s\n' "$line"      # print the first line that was read
    cat                        # continue reading & printing the output
}
```

<sup>**remark:** You also need to disable any output buffering that `run test` might have.</sup>

Comment: thank you very much. Still some issues with that. Please have a look to the last edit.

Comment: I see. As you don't even need to parse the output of `run test` to get your ID then your use-case is completely different; just start your script with `run test &`, that's all you have to do

Comment: @Fravedona sounds good BUT i still get "no tests running" since it gets executed too soon (when the test didn't even started yet). Could something like `run test & sleep 1 & list test running` work?

Comment: i test it out. IT WORKS! But: i can't kill the process (it's not required for now, but i can't immagine that i couldn't stop the program) and i updated it to save the ID in a file. For the rest, perfect, thank you very much!

Comment: just one small question: is it preferable to use `sed` (in an efficient way, not like in my code) or as you did with regex?